# Unable to create nested duplication of div elements in forms using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a dynamic form which allows the user to add fields on the fly. So there are two fields that can be added. one of the fields is a subset of the other. Like this

```
Category 1
 1. field1
 2. field2
Category 2
 1. field1
 2. field2
 3. field3
```

The user should be able to add both categories and also the fields inside them.

SO this is what I've came up so far. http://jsbin.com/mufidu/2/edit?html,js,output

Javascript part :

```js
cgCnt = 1;
cpCnt = 1;
function add_cg(cgId){
    cgCnt = cgCnt+1;
    var cgOriginal = document.getElementById(cgId);
    var cgClone = cgOriginal.cloneNode(true);

    cgClone.id = "cg" + cgCnt;
    cgOriginal.parentNode.appendChild(cgClone);
    var cpInCg = cgClone.getElementByTagName("div");
    cpInCg.id = "cg"+cgCnt+"cp1";   
}
function add_cp(addCpId, addCgId){
    cpCnt = cpCnt + 1;
    var cpOriginal = document.getElementById(addCpId);
    cpClone = cpOriginal.cloneNode(true);
    cpClone.id = addCgId+"cp"+cpCnt;
    cpOriginal.parentNode.appendChild(cpClone);
}
```

HTML part :

```html
<form>
    <div id="cg1">
        <input type="text" placeholder="covergroup"\>
        <input type="button" style="position: relative;" value = "+" onClick="add_cg(this.parentNode.id)">
        <!<input type="button" id="removeCgCp" style="position:relative;" value = "-" onClick="remove_cg(this.parentNode.id)">
        <br /><br />
        <div id="cg1cp1">
            <input type="text" placeholder="coverpoint" style="position:relative; left:50px">
            <input type="button" style="position: relative; left:50px" value="+" onClick="add_cp(this.parentNode.id , this.parentNode.parentNode.id)">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It is working more or less as I wanted it to be, but after creating a new category, when I try to create and additional fields in that category, they are being appended in the first category. I've placed some alert statements to see what's going on and figured out that the lines

```js
var cpInCg = cgClone.getElementByTagName("div");
cpInCg.id = "cg"+cgCnt+"cp1";
```

are not functioning as I expected. I was trying to change the ID of the subcategory field after cloning (as this ID would be same as the ID of the original). But my alert statements show me that this id is not being changed.

Is there a better approach to this ?

Thanks.

P.S : I don't know jQuery yet and just started learning Javascript.

Comment: There's no method `getElementByTagName`. There's `getElementsByTagName` -- it returns a collection of all the elements with that tag, and you have to iterate over it.

Comment: Oh. I tried getElementsByTagName too but I din't realize that the output is an array with one element.
so I just put cpInCg[0].id and it worked. Thanks a lot.